# Where does SQL Server store the SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Where does SQL Server store the SSIS packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use SQL Server 2005 in combination with Visual Studio 2005.  So all my SSIS projects by default will be at

C:\Documents and Settings\santosh\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects

Let me know if you have your SQL Server set up in a different environment or if you have made changes to your Visual Studio options.

If you dont find your projects at above mentioned location,  look at the defined default projects path in Tools>Options in Visual Studio.

This should help.

Comment: This is totally inaccurate, you are answering where Visual Studio projects are held on your local workstation.

Answer (score 28):

Depending on how you choose to deploy them, they are either stored within the MSDB database or on the file system. Here's how you do both:

- [File System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137970.aspx)
- [Server (msdb)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137565.aspx)

Comment: These links have been updated and they are no longer useful. They point to a page that tells you how to save a package in SSDT, which is about as useful as it sounds.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from SSIS 2012, there is a new place for packages - [SSIS Catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479588.aspx), stored in SSISDB database (default name, can be changed on creation). It is created by SSMS wizard (not created during installation of SQL Server) and accessible both as User's database and Integration Services branch in SSMS Database connection.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the physical location of the ssis package is at:
C:\Program files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Dts\packages

once you deploy it, you will find them in MSDB database in the sqlserver.

Answer (score 3):

By Default it will be store at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Packages in sql server 2012.

In subsequent version such as 2008,2010,2012,2014 it will be at 90\100\110\120 folder in above path.

But again if you are deploying ssis package location depends on the deployment type.

In File system-You can set the path.

Answer (score 2):

If you have deployed packages in the SQL Server, by default they will be stored under MSDB. You can see stored packages by connecting to Integration Services of the SQL Server and looking under "Stored Packages" --> MSDB.

Answer (score 2):

Check your SQL Server Instance and there's a place called MSDB ( i.e The Database) The Default Configuration is to store your SSIS packages in that Database

Answer (score 1):

The package store can include both the msdb database and the folders in the file system, only msdb, or only folders in the file system. In msdb, packages are saved to the sysssispackages table. This table includes a folderid column that identifies the logical folder to which the package belongs. The logical folders provide a useful way to group packages saved to msdb in the same way that folders in the file system provide a way to group packages saved to the file system. Rows in the sysssispackagefolders table in msdb define the folders.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS packages can be deployed with 2 options (using the wizard for example):
File Sytem Deployment
or SQL Server Deployment

Answer (score 0):

1-By Default it will be store at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Packages in sql server 2012.

2-In subsequent version such as 2008,2010 it will be at 90\100 folder in above path.

3-SSIS Package location depends on the type of deployment.

4-File system-You can set the path.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to SQL server Integration services. 
Under Stored Packages - > MSDB -> **any folder you created and imported the SSIS package**