# Accessing SQL Server .dtsx packages without integration services

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, etl

I've saved some `.dtsx` integration packages, which do run, to the SQL Server instance rather than the file system.

I'd like to clean these up and redo them, but I can't find a way to access and delete them.  I've attempted connecting to the server using integration services, but I get a "Specified service does not exist as an installed service"

I've been trying to find how to enable the service, but everything I've seen seems to lead me to a full reinstall which is not a viable solution at this time.

If I'm missing some documentation which shows how to enable the services on an already installed instance that'd be plenty, but if not I'd like to know if there's some other way to access these files so I can clean them up and replace some of them without having to point everything to a local folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without integration services installed you cannot access these packages if they are stored in SQL Server database (not File System).

Referring to [Package Management documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/package-management-ssis-service?view=sql-server-2017):

> By default, the Stored Packages folder contains two folders: **File System and MSDB**. The File System folder lists the packages that are saved to the file system. The location of these files is specified in the configuration file for the Integration Services service. The default folder is the Packages folder, located in **%Program Files%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS**.
>
> The **MSDB folder** lists the Integration Services packages that have been saved to the SQL Server msdb database on the server. The **sysssispackages table contains the packages saved to msdb**.
>
> To view the list of packages in the package store, you must open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to Integration Services.

**Additional Information**

- [Where does SQL Server store the SSIS packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054072/where-does-sql-server-store-the-ssis-packages)
- [Save Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/save-packages?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I have come a cross this before, a few points.  There is no 100\DTS folder, only 140.  It does have a DTS\Packages, which is blank.  Further I cannot find any MSDB folder, although I did find the table in the database.  Is the short answer then that I cannot modify my current install to enable SSIS without a full reinstall and will have to directly handle the tables?

Comment: @Eji1700 100 is related to sql 2008, 140 is for 2017. In addition, there is no MSDB folder in windows. It is only shown in management studio.

Comment: @Eji1700 you need to install Ssis. You can modify current installation without reinstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I am using sql server 2016/2017

I normally use DTSs to copy data across  databases or servers.

the DTS package gets saved in a table in the msdb database and you can see the code of the package using the query below.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SET NOCOUNT ON

select * from [msdb].[dbo].sysssispackages 


SELECT [name] ,[id] ,[description] ,[createdate] ,
CAST(CAST([packagedata] as varbinary(max)) as xml) AS PackageSource ,[packagetype] ,
[vermajor] ,[verminor] ,[verbuild] ,[vercomments] ,[verid] ,[isencrypted] 
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysssispackages] K
ORDER BY K.createdate DESC
```

[image]

if you want the code of the package click on the XML link